# Write an algorithm that finds array elements that sum up to some value

Tags: algorithms, arrays, search-problem

> The following is a pseudo-code named `PractOne`. It takes a finite list `A` of real numbers and gives the pair `(Alp,Bet)`, with `Alp` representing the maximum value of the entry in `A` and `Bet` representing the index of `Alp` in `A`. `Bet` is not always unique.
>
> ```
> function PractOne(A)
>     let Bet = 1
>     let Alp = A[Bet]
>     for i = 1 to length(A)
>         if A[i] > Alp then
>         let Bet = i
>         let Alp = A[Bet]
>     end if
>     next i
>     return (Alp,Bet)
> end function
> ```
>
> Please note that the function `length (A)` takes finite list `A=[b_1,..., b_j]` and gives the number of elements `j` in `A`. Also, `A[i]` gives the `i`th element in the finite list `A=[b_1,..., b_j]`.
>
> 1. Create an algorithm (named `PractTwo`) which takes a finite and non-empty list `A` of real numbers which are sorted in increasing order and a real number `C`, if there exists two indices `i`, `j`, such that `1<= i<= j<= length(A)` and `A[i]+A[j]=C`, then `PractTwo(A,C)` gives the pair `(A[i],A[j])`. When there is a case where more than one pair of indices exists with the required properties, then the function will give one of the valid pairs. Also, if the equality  `A[i]+A[j]=C` is not satisfied for `i` and `j`, such that `1<= i<= j<= length(A)`, then the function will give back an empty pair `(,)`.
>
>    Ensure, `PractTwo` completes its search with a maximum of `d*Length(A)` steps, where `d>0` is some constant not dependable on on `A`.

I have an idea...I'm thinking `PractTwo` requires more steps to factor into it the `1<= i<= j<= length (A)`, so...

> ```
> function PractTwo(A)
>     let Bet = 1
>     let Alp = A[Bet]
>     let j = A[i]
>     for i = 1 to length(A)
>         if A[i] > Alp then
>         let Bet = i
>         let Alp = A[Bet]
>     end if
>     next i
>     return (Alp,Bet)
> end function
> ```

I don't think this is complete, is what I've done so far correct?

> 2. Also, show that `PractTwo` gives back the correct value. Also explain how the implementation of `PractTwo` is completed in at most `d*Length(A)` steps.

Comment: This is a problem statement, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or about specific steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: That fact that you were not even able to choose a descriptive title suggests that you don't really understand the task. I don't know what you mean by "where would the loop go" and why there would be two looks. What have you tried, at all?

Comment: Since this is a pretty standard exercise problem I'm quite sure we've discussed it before, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your comments, I will take a look at the links you have provided, if you do find a similar exercise problem which has been discussed please post the link here. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

PractOne seems ok. Could be very slightly improved by starting the
loop at 2.

PractTwo  is wrong, even without considering what it is supposed to
do. You write (line 4) : `let j = A[i]`, but `i` is undefined. I have no idea what you are trying to do.

You have to find `A[i]` and `A[j]` in linear time. Linear time is the
requirement to use at most `d*Length(A)` steps.

Achieving linear time requires being a bit more subtle in the
computation. You use the fact that the array is sorted in increasing order. You start
looking for `A[i]` starting from one end (say from small indices), and
looking for `A[j]` from the other end (say from large indices), until
`i` meets `j`, stopping before if you find a solution.  Sometimes you
increase `i` and sometimes you decrease `j` depending on whether the
last sum `A[i]+A[j]` was greater or smaller than `C`.

I let you work it out in more details, and do the explanation.